# Javascript: Awaiting resolved promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I would like to know, if awaiting a resolved promise, will lead to a synchronous code execution or may lead to asynchronous one.

I made this little snippet to check on browsers :

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('exec promise');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('executed promise');
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

(async () => {
  console.log('start');
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e8; i += 1) {
    await promise;
  }
  console.log('end');
})();
```

And it looks like browsers make it synchronous (considering the screen freeze).

BUT ... is it due to browser specific implementation ? Or by design ?

Comment: Using `await` inside a classic for loop works synchronously, yes.

Comment: Sequential, not synchronous. The IIFE still returns (a promise) immediately, and other code runs independently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative demo that doesn't freeze the browser (which I think is getting the way of what we're trying to show), and which shows the opposite behaviour to your initial conclusion:

```js
const p = new Promise((r) => r());

p.then(() => {

  (async() => {
    console.log('a');
    await p;
    console.log('p');
  })()
  console.log('b');

});
```

In this case, we get hold of `p`, a resolved promise.  We then kick off an async function that awaits it.  The output is:

> a 
> b 
> p

IE the async function still returned control back (and `b` was logged) when it hit the `await` on the already resolved `p`.  Only after `b` was logged and the event loop was free to return execution back to after the `await` was `p` subsequently logged.

Is this standard behaviour? Yes.

The [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#await) effectively turns the awaited expression to the `then` part of a promise, and in steps 9 and 10 of a [subsequent step](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen) makes the decision on how to proceed.

> 9. If promise.[[PromiseState]] is pending, then 
>    a. Append fulfillReaction as the last element of the List that is promise.[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]. 
>    b. Append rejectReaction as the last element of the List that is promise.[PromiseRejectReactions]].
> 10. Else if promise.[[PromiseState]] is fulfilled, 
>     a. then Let value be promise.[[PromiseResult]]. 
>     b. Let fulfillJob be NewPromiseReactionJob(fulfillReaction, value) 
>     c. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(fulfillJob.[[Job]], fulfillJob.[[Realm]]).

Step 9 says if it's pending, to add the generated `then` to the list of things to be called when the promise is fulfilled.

Step 10 gets to the heart of your question - it says if it's fulfilled already, to enqueue the job - ie to place it on the queue of things to be called back.

The spec effectively says that an `await` should never return synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. You freeze the event loop there, because the promise has already been resolved, the next await operator will wait&resolve for the next promise descriptor on the same iteration of the event loop. But this behavior can be platform-specific, depending on which promise implementation you're actually using - native or shim.

```
const promise= Promise.resolve();

(async()=>{
    for(let i=0; i< 10000000; i++) {
        await promise;
    }
    console.log('end');
})()

setTimeout(()=> console.log('nextEventLoopTick'), 0);
```

Will output the follwing:

```
end
nextEventLoopTick
```

As you can see, the async fn will be fully resolved before setTimeout. So, this indicates that the async function is resolved on the same eventloop tick.